# gateway on IP1, DHCP/DNS on IP2 -> network down

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

My gateway has IP 10.10.10.1, and I am trying to get a Windows Server (10.10.10.2) to provide DHCP and DNS services. I have set up DHCP and DNS in the Windows server, and disabled them in the router (Netgear).

However, I am running into problems. It seems that hosts on the LAN cannot find any DNS.

The IP assignment throws the following warning: "Multiple default gateways are intended to provide redundancy to a single network (such as an intranet or the Internet). They will not function properly when the gateways are on two separate, disjoint networks (such as one on your intranet and one on the Internet). Do you want to save this configuration?".

I suspect that I have done something wrong with the assignment of routers and gateways, but I cannot figure it out.

`Ipconfig /all` gives the following:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WsKeller
Primary Dns Suffix. . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Primary virtual switch):
Connection-specific DNS Suffix. :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-C4-7A-xx-A2-CE
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5da3:e1ae:9f6f:d8a9%12(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.2(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 487375994
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-FF-4C-7D-0C-C4-7A-C2-A2-CF
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.2, 8.8.8.8
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Does 10.10.10.2 have more than one ethernet adapter, with another default gateway? Having dhcp-server on another machine than the gateway is very much possible, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Not really. Server 10.10.10.2 has 5 eth ports but I disabled 4 of them. The single enabled port is connected to a Hyper-V virtual switch, and that switch is in turn connected to the main 10.10.10.2 server and to five virtual machines (4 linux and 1 windows10pro).

Comment: Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
10.10.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.2    266
10.10.10.2  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.2    266
10.10.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.2    266
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.2    266
Persistent Routes:
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.10.10.1  Default

Comment: Above: I was thinking that maybe the routing table would bring some clarity.

Comment: Rather unreadable, add the table to the question, so it can be formatted properly. But it seems there is only one default route.

Comment: Dear Lenne, thank you so much for bearing with me! It seems that I had mistakenly added 10.10.10.1 to the DHCP scope options and 10.10.10.2 to the DHCP server options! All is clear now. Except that my arch linux hyper-v virtual machines do not seem to be assigned their proper IP reservation and end up in the DHCP pool. curiously, this does not seem to happen in the case of a single win10 hyper-v VM on the same server. Is there anything I must do to ensure that the VMs are given the right IP?